# MS dynamics CRM add record to a1:N realtionship within C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I have CRM entity called C which has N:1 relationship with entity Account. Account has 1:N relationship with entity B

Problem Statement:

Create a **new record** for **Entity C** with **update of existing Account(a)** (Update in existing account(a) is : **a** already had two records b1 and b2 of type Entity B . **I need to add third record b3 of type Entity B**)

Following is my code

```
_context.Attach(c.relationshipNameWithAccount);
_context.UpdateObject(c.relationshipNameWithAccount);
_context.AddObject(c);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

This code is executing successfully.

It is **Adding** a new record in **C**(as expected) also **updating fields** in existing record a (as expected) but **not adding** b3 in existing account **a**(not expected).

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use AssociateRequest for Your Association like this

EntityReferenceCollection relatedEntities = new EntityReferenceCollection();

relatedEntities.Add(new EntityReference(B, BId));

Relationship relationship = new Relationship("B_RelationName_A");

_service.Associate(A, AId, relationship, relatedEntities);